# Install ubuntu touch on toro

Tags: ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

Just wondering if there is an update to the problem of ubuntu touch not working on toro phones, and if not I am curious if it will ever be supported. I know the mobile phone market progresses at a rapid speed and people are focusing on the edge project.